# How to remove the underline for link in html

Tags: html, css

How to remove the underline from the link? That's my code
I try type some code in there, but still not working

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.top {
  color:black;
  font-family:Calibri;
  text-decoration:none;
}

table {

}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="Home.html"><p class="top">Home</p></a></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `.top` class changes the style for the `p` tag, however it is the `a` tag that sets the `text-decoration`, so you will have to specify that or add to your `a` tag another class and set it's `text-decoration` attribute.

A possible way:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="Home.html" class="no-underline">
        <p class="top">Home</p>
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

and

```
.no-underline {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `text-decoration: none` to the `<a>` tag itself, not to the `<p>` which is inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

Should be this:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`text-decoration:none`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

try,

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced `.top` by the `a` tag

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
a {
    color:black;
    font-family:Calibri;
    text-decoration:none;
}

table {

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Home</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.css">`enter code here`

</head>

<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="Home.html"><p class="top">Home</p></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```